# JavaFX - Trying to display a maze/labyrinth on a canvas

Tags: canvas, javafx, maze

So I am trying to display a randomly generated maze on a canvas.

Program structure:

1. I create Tile-Objects which are basically the little squares you see on the image below.
2. These Tiles have 4 walls from which one is open/traversable which should result in deleting the line (wall) of the Tile-Objects/squares. This is where I have problems.
3. These squares with black borders on the canvas are actually black squares with white squares placed on top of them.

My question is: How can I properly display the maze on the canvas?

Method which draws everything on the canvas:

Vocabulary:

- tileLength: length of each individual square on the canvas
- tileHeight: height of each individual square on the canvas
- gc: GraphicsContext2D of my canvas
- isOpen: boolean which tells if a wall is traversable (e.g. should be deleted on the canvas) or not

I just realised I should maybe explain how exactly the switch statement works. Basically each Tile-Object has 4 Wall-Objects. Each Wall-Object has amongst other things an integer attribute with a range of 1-4 which indicates the position of the wall. So 1=top, 2=right, 3=bottom and 4=left. The rest should be understandable from here on.

```
    public void drawMaze(Canvas canvas, Tile[][] maze) {
        double tileLength = canvas.getWidth() / maze.length;
        double tileHeight = canvas.getHeight() / maze[0].length;

        for (int x = 0; x < maze.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < maze[x].length; y++) {
                gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
                gc.fillRect(x * tileLength, y * tileHeight, tileLength, tileHeight);

                gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                gc.fillRect(x * tileLength + tileLength * 0.01, y * tileHeight + tileHeight * 0.01, tileLength - tileLength * 0.02, tileHeight - tileHeight * 0.02);

                //The following part should remove the lines
                for(Wall w : maze[x][y].getWalls()) {
                    if(w.isOpen()) {
                        switch(w.getPosition()) {
                            case 1: gc.clearRect(x * tileLength + tileLength * 0.01, y * tileHeight - tileHeight * 0.8, tileLength - tileLength * 0.02, tileHeight - tileHeight * 0.02);                                
                                break;
                            case 2: gc.clearRect(x * tileLength + tileLength * 0.8, y * tileHeight + tileHeight * 0.01, tileLength - tileLength * 0.02, tileHeight - tileHeight * 0.02);
                                break;
                            case 3: gc.clearRect(x * tileLength + tileLength * 0.01, y * tileHeight + tileHeight * 0.8, tileLength - tileLength * 0.02, tileHeight - tileHeight * 0.02);
                                break;
                            case 4: gc.clearRect(x * tileLength - tileLength * 0.8, y * tileHeight + tileHeight * 0.01, tileLength - tileLength * 0.02, tileHeight - tileHeight * 0.02);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Grid before removing the lines:

[image: img]

Faulty display of maze:

[image: img]